# Expose DOM element with a prototype in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this current implementation (which I know is not correct):

```
    kf.Ui.modal = function(){
        this.el = $('#modal');
        this.els = {
            done: this.el.find('[name="modal-btn-done"]')
        }
    };

    kf.Ui.modal.prototype.done = function(){
        return this.els.done;
    };

    var modal = new kf.Ui.modal();
    modal.done().on('click', function(){ alert('done clicked') });
```

If you see what I'm trying to achieve here, how can this be done? So, I'd like to expose a DOM element contained within the `this.el` and allow myself to attach an event onto the instantiation.

Comment: Don't you have a typo? Shouldn't it be `modal.done().on...`?

Comment: @drinchev You're right. Doesn't feel like it needs to be a function though.

Comment: Everything looks correct to me now that you fixed the `.done()` call. Your `this.el.find()` will return a jQuery object with the matched DOM elements, and then your `.done()` will return that jQuery object, and your `.on()` will bind the handler.

Comment: ...if you didn't want the `.done()` function call, you could just use `modal.els.done.on(...`

Comment: I think that the prototype isn't really needed. As you're attaching `this.els` on the instance of the modal you can just access it like this: `modal.els.done.on...`

Comment: I'm not really sure what the problem is. This works just fine. If you're not adding HTML after you create the modal, you can make it not a function. But if it needs to reflect the current state of the DOM, it needs to be a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically everything is pretty good, but I couldn't write such a big comment

The way I would do this would be :

```
function Modal(element) {
    this.el = $(element);
    this.done = this.el.find("button");
}

var modal = new Modal('div#mymodal');

modal.done.on('click', ...);
```

Comment: There'll be a problem if the button is added after the Modal is created. Also, it's less efficient to select based on `div#mymodal` and not just `#mymodal`.

Comment: Yep in this case it could be `var that = this; this.done = function(cb) { that.el.on('click', 'button', cb); }` and later `modal.done(function() { console.log("I'm done"); });`